# log the request/response body in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am using Microsoft Asp.net core api hosted on IIS. I would like to log the request body (XML or JSON) and the response body for each post in new log file on the server.

I tried to use Serilog but nothing show in new log file on the server.

**Startup** :

```
 var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            loggerFactory.AddFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "APILogs.txt"));
            loggerFactory.AddFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Log-{Date}.txt"));
```

**Contriller** :

```
readonly ILogger<ServicesController> _logger;

        public ServicesController(ILogger<ServicesController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

**Controller Api function:**

```
        _logger.LogInformation("test");
```

Comment: How are you trying to implement that? Could please share your issue? You can have a look at the [example here in official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: The issue is the log file empty

Comment: Could you share the implentations? Did you have a chance to to debug that? While debugging are the information there?

Comment: I could not debug the code. nothing sow in log file. I will post the implementation

Comment: I post the implementation

Comment: All right, let's investigate the issues, are you getting anyting on `AllId`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247326/discussion-between-asmaalghamdi-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).